# how to setup sf cli in docker that run as anonymous user

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, docker, sf

i am installing cf cli in docker. it works fine when I run the docker as root. but when I run it as anonymous user: `docker run -it --user 1001 sf_docker:latest bash` and then executing:
`sf version`
it gives me this error:

```bash
app$ sf version
    SystemError: A system error occurred: uv_os_get_passwd returned ENOENT (no such file or directory)
    Code: ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR
```

i even have in my docker file this lines, but for no avail:

```
RUN chmod -R g=u /usr/local/bin/sf
RUN echo "ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/sf" >> /etc/sudoers
RUN echo "${USER_NAME:-default}:x:$(id -u):0:${USER_NAME:-default} user:${HOME}:/sbin/nologin" >> /etc/passwd
```

please help. the user can by any random number or whatever.